# Unbound properties as arguments for components and views

Tags: ember.js

I'm in the process of optimizing my Ember application by following some of the tips given in [this presentation](http://www.robharper.ca/ember-on-mobile/performance.html#/intro). I'm wondering how I can give unbound properties as arguments to components and views. For instance in

```
{{my-component arg=unboundProperty}}
```

I want `unboundProperty` to be unbound, i.e. it takes as value its first non-null value (set after the models in the route has been resolved) but does not propagate to the component when its value changes. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to do it you can use a computed property without defining dependencies.  The computed property will be calculated the first time it's requested, and then it will never think it needs to update, so it will never update.

```
App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  realProperty: 'fooBar',
  unboundProperty: function(){
    return this.get('realProperty');
  }.property()
});



{{my-component arg=unboundProperty}}
```

You could do the same thing in your component

```
App.MyComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  readOnceArg: function(){
    return this.get('arg');
  }.property()
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but I feel it's a bit cumbersome, having to define an extra property where it's really just an unbound version of an already existing property. I assume then that there's no dedicated syntax for this, something similar to the `{{unbound}}` syntax for templates?